# How can I display the jquery datetime picker underneath the input field?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datetime

I have been combing through my css file to try to get the jquery date picker to appear directly below the input field: "When should we contact you?" When clicked, the datetime picker will display far below. I am sure I am doing something stupid, but banging my head up against this wall is providing no results...

Most oddly, When I Inspect Element in chrome, and exit, it fixes itself. I have read in other posts that this means faulty css somewhere, however I have been unable to locate the issue. Any advice would be most appreciated.

http://www2.sungevity.com/l/35342/2016-01-08/g3cl6l

both the .js and .css files are publicly hosted. This is a Pardot landing page, which is making things even more stupid...

Comment: in FF, it doesn't show a datetime picker at all. Also, please use jsfiddle or similar to host your minimalized code example - this has the benefit that others can modify your code and save it.

Comment: Ive tested in FF and it seems to work for me. You have to click on the date entry field for the box to show up, and when it does it is well below where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Soo happy to have figured out a solution, Thought I would share the love.

I went into the js file and found that there was an event handler for relocating the picker on a window resize, which is why it fixed it self when I looked at the chrome inspector or resized the window. I took that same relocate handler and put it before the initial call // Show a picker. Now it relocates before it loads and no one is the wiser. Not the prettiest solution but it works with a short line of code.